# Прежде, но прежний. Куда исчезла "д"?

Tags: словообразование

Я не смог объяснить внуку, почему слово "прежний", являющееся однокоренным с "прежде", пишется без буквы "д". Предполагаю, что у них связь с понятием "перед", но потом в одном случае "д" чередуется с "ж", а в другом  - с "жд"? Может, коллеги помогут мне?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Прежний - прилагательное, образованное от основы сравнит. степени преже, преж (вост.-слав.*perdje)-тот, который впереди. Образовано оно одновременно со старославянским "прежде", а не от него.В говорах до сих пор сохранились наречия преже, переже, пережь, прежь, допрежь. ЖД  - признак старославянизма, Ж- исконно русского слова. Правда, значение слова поменялось на совр.-"минувший, былой" и "тот же самый": остался прежним, тем, который был раньше, перед этим. Так что они просто исторически однокоренные, а так корни разные.

Answer (score 1):

Про перед я не знаю то, но наверное. 
а пар с чередованием Ж и Д/ЖД много. Невежда и невежда, гражданин и горожанин, одежный и одежда. Кажется, даже надежда и надежный. 
Которые с ЖД, это старославянские слова, а Ж - древнерусские. Они когда-то разделились, а потом снова смешались в русском языке.